# Скопировать все слова \ DelphiXE

Tags: delphi

Есть текстовый файл, в нем текст:

```
№34434(Принято_15)_приход-01.01.2018\№544341(Принято_7)_приход-08.01.2018
№84434(Принято_17)_приход-06.01.2018\№944381(Принято_9)_приход-04.01.2018
№74434(Принято_43)_приход-09.01.2018\№544341(Принято_12)_приход-04.01.2018
```

Как вытянуть и записать построчно все между скобок - **()**. То есть на выходе получится текст:

```
Принято_15
Принято_17
Принято_43
Принято_7
Принято_9
Принято_12
```

Делаю так но у меня получается вытянуть только первые слова и полно пустых строк:

```
 Readln(f1,s);
    s:=Copy(s,Pos('(',s)+1,Pos(')',s)-Pos('(',s)-1);
Writeln(f2,s);
```

Примечание: слов со скобками в одной строки может быть и больше.

Comment: Регулярные выражения используйте =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Их пока только изучаю... Хотелось через pos сделать, но я так понимаю что это не просто ?

Comment: ничего сложного через pos, просто это задача для регулярок =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Не подскажите как правильно сделать через pos, ну реально заглохла я на этом моменте :).....

Comment: чтобы сделать через pos, вам нужно завести переменную в которую будет ложится текущаяя позиция поиска, и последующий поиск должен выполнятся не с начала строки а из этого положения.
т.е. решение в одну строку - не выйдет

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, Ну теперь я точно запуталась.... :). Буду пробовать, но даже и не знаю получится ли....

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно вывести вначале первые скобки для всех строк, потом вторые, потом третьи? Или вначале выводим все скобки для первой строки, потом все скобки для второй и т.д.?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Идеально было бы: вначале выводим все скобки для первой строки, потом все скобки для второй и так далее...

Comment: @Татьяна, использование такого подхода навеяно заданием или желанием разобраться или просто непониманием регулярных функций? просто все дополнения вопроса, все его модификации - требуют минимальных изменений при решении через регулярные выражения, а если точно то только изменения самого регулярного выражения, причем зачастую незначительно, в отличии от вашего подхода, где в некоторых случаях код придется дополнять или менять кардинально.

Comment: @ Владимир Клыков, Желанием разобраться. Просто, иногда, мне тяжело разобраться - выходя из склада моего ума, как это не печально звучит, но самокритику, я всегда, применяю в свою сторону!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var
  StartPos: Integer;
  EndPos: Integer;
  s: string;
  part: string;
begin
  while not Eof(f1) do begin
    Readln(f1,s);
    StartPos := Pos('(', s);
    while StartPos > 0 do begin
      EndPos := PosEx(')', s, StartPos + 1);
      if EndPos = -1 then
        raise Exception.Create('")" not found');
      part := Copy(s, StartPos + 1, EndPos - StartPos - 1);
      Writeln(f2, part);
      StartPos := PosEx('(', s, EndPos + 1);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Функция `PosEx` определена в модуле `StrUtils`. Если у вас Delphi XE3 или новее, то вместо функции `PosEx` можно использовать функцию `Pos`. Начиная с этой версии у функции `Pos` появился третий параметр

Comment: PosEx это какая версия студии или какой файл надо подключить? в Xe7 по стандарту не видит такой =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, подключите юнит `StrUtils` в раздел `uses`. Думаю, что функция не новая, хотя кто знает)

Comment: @Dima Да, не новая, спасибо за напоминание про его существование, глянул код и не понимай зачем он применен =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Он применен, потому что изначально в функции `Pos` было только два параметра. А когда появился третий - я не помню

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Со времен D7 там было всегда 3 параметра =) Не суть =) главное что код работает =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Вы что-то путаете. Еще в D2007 там два параметра. В [2009](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Pos@RawByteString@RawByteString.html) тоже два. Аналогично в [XE2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Pos). А вот в [XE3](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Pos) уже три параметра

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, под рукой нету этих древностей, на работе гляну, там есть как раз D7 и XE2

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, А такой вопрос по коду возник: А как вытянуть все между апострофами (по такому же принципу), то есть - 'И тут текст'. Delphi понимает апостроф как окончание строки и выдает ошибку. Читала про это в интернете и говорят что апостроф в строке надо удваивать. То есть я так поняла StartPos := Pos('''', s); или как правильно ? И такая же ситуация когда знаки одинаковые +и тут текст+. То есть не вытягивает код с одинаковых знаков и между апастрофами. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @Татьяна Вы правильно прочитали. Апострофы нужно удваивать. Чтобы работало с одинаковыми знаками, я модифицировал код

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, Все разобралась! Спасибо большое, изначально неправильно делала, теперь все работает отлично!

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, А еще такой вопрос (Если нужно то могу тему создать): Как в этот код добавить условие - если в тексте что между знаками () - иметься знак + , то извлекать текст, если нет знака + ,то не извлекать. Я спрашиваю ради интереса.

Comment: @Татьяна `part := ...; if Pos('+', part) > 0 tnen...`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, ВСЕ, решила все проблемы, с этим кодом. Больше глупых вопросов не будет по этому вопросу. 1000 плюсов Вам, все работает отлично.

Answer (score 3):

```
Var
  s:string;
  sPos:Integer;
  ePos:Integer;

begin
  s :='№34434(Принято_15)_приход-01.01.2018\№544341(Принято_7)_приход-08.01.2018';
  sPos:=1;
  while sPos>0 do
  Begin
    sPos:=Pos('(',s,sPos);
    ePos:=Pos(')',s,sPos);
    if(ePos-sPos>0) then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(copy(s,sPos+1,ePos-sPos-1));
    sPos:=ePos;
  End;
```

Это просто демо как именно сделать через Pos

Тоже самое на регулярке:

```
Var
  s:string;
  i:Integer;
  RegEx : TRegEx;
begin
  s :='№34434(Принято_15)_приход-01.01.2018\№544341(Принято_7)_приход-08.01.2018';
  RegEx:=TRegEx.Create('(\([^)]+\))+');
  with RegEx.Matches(s) do
  Begin
    for i := 0 to count-1 do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Item[i].Value);
  end;
```

p.s. для регулярки можно убрать скобки, для этого регулярное выражение меняете на вот такое:

```
'(\(([^)]+)\))+'
```

а результат получаете вот так:

```
Item[i].Groups[2].Value
```